# Using jQuery .css() without a specific property

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'll be using a textarea as a code editor. I want to get the value of the textarea and it as the CSS for a specified element.

HTML

```
<textarea class-"editor">
  background: blue;
  border: 1px solid pink;
</textarea>
```

JS

```
$('.editor').keyup(function(){
  var editor_contents = $('.editor').val();
  $('#element').css(editor_contents);
});
```

As you can see, I don't want to choose a specific CSS property to target. I want to apply the value of the textarea in a string on the style property of #element.

Comment: to which style property you want to assign the value to.... you need to target a property to assign the value

Comment: give some sample values of editor_contents

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use `cssText` property, this is the way to do it in jQuery:

```
$('.editor').keyup(function(){
  var editor_contents = $('.editor').val();
  $('#element').css("cssText",editor_contents);
});
```

That supposes `editor_contents` is a string containing any CSS rule.

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/2kDzL/)

Comment: Thanks! I also want to do the reverse. I want to get the CSS of the element and apply it as the value of the textarea. How can I get the CSS of the element as a string?

Comment: @Moppy use: `$('.editor').val($('#element').attr("style"));` http://jsfiddle.net/2kDzL/1/

Comment: @A.Wolff: ignoring any other CSS id or class styles though.

Answer (score 4):

Don't bother too much with fancy jQuery functions then -- just assign directly to the `style` attribute of the element:

```
$('.editor').keyup(function () {
  var editor_contents = $('.editor').val();
  $('#element').attr('style', editor_contents);
});
```